# Are thousands of expired keys bad on performance for Redis?

Tags: performance, monitoring, cache, redis

I'm new to Redis, so I don't know which metrics I should care about and how to monitor its healthiness and responsiveness.

My colleagues and I are maintaining a software, which uses Redis heavily for caching. Sometimes Redis will slow down since too many requests are happening at the same time, but sadly I'm not sure which of our processes to blame (it's a legacy software project with dozens of processes running at the same time plus time triggered processes via cron).

I can see, that Redis has thousands to 1.5 millions of expired keys in its store, does this somehow harm the performance while adding or querying new/other keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The number of expired keys is an aggregate since the server was started or had its stats reset, and doesn't necessarily relate to actual load.

Look at Redis' log file and the [`SLOWLOG`](https://redis.io/commands/slowlog) to try and identify the root cause.